# Bookmarks in File, aka Nautilus only open home directory

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I searched through the previous questions regarding bookmarks in Nautilus/File, but I don't see my question asked - apologies if I missed something along the way.

I'm using a new install of Ubuntu 14.04.1. What's happening is that when I connect to a network place, say `proxy.library.emhs.edu/data1/html`, a shortcut appears in the left sidebar. When I close out, then reopen and click on the shortcut, it opens my Home folder on that server, eg `proxy.library.emhs.edu/home/myacct`.

Frustrating I assure you. I looked at the config file in `~/.config/nautilus` and the shortcuts that have been created all contain the correct path, however clicking on the bookmark only opens the home directory.

Am I totally missing something? How can I configure File/Nautilus to open a particular directory instead of my home folder? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this shortcut appear under the Networks section or the Bookmarks section?

Comment: The shortcut appears under "Network" in the left-hand column of the Files/Nautilus window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper bookmark, made by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or other means of adding bookmarks, will create an entry in the *Bookmarks* section of the sidepane. This entry will remember the location you were in when you created the bookmark. The entry under the *Network* section is due to Nautilus remembering the location and other connection settings for the server.

[image]

Here, the `lab` entry under the Bookmarks section opens in my `~/Downloads` directory, because that's where I bookmarked it.

Comment: Ah, did not get the whole difference between shortcut and Bookmark, cool thanks!